# Conditional format to highlight date in date range

Tags: excel, vba

I have set as dates in row A all the Sundays of the year from A7-A60. I would like a conditional format so the current Sunday will be always highlighted whenever one opens that excel file.

I've tried setting that with WEEKDAY but could get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "current Sunday" you mean the one just passed, so on Saturday 3rd Jan the previous Sunday (`28th December 2014`) will be highlighted.....but during the period from 4th January to 10th January 2015 the `Sunday 4th January 2015` date will be highlighted ...and so on through the year

To do that select the whole range and use this formula in conditional formatting:

`=A7=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1`

That works because the formula `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1` always gives you the previous Sunday, so it's sufficient to see if A7 matches that date.

As your range only contains Sundays this version will also work in this case

`=(A7<=TODAY())*(A7>TODAY()-7)`

.....because that will highlight any date in the current week

Comment: for "the current Sunday" i meant to one ahead of today's date.
So today the Sunday(1/4/2015) will be highlighted

Comment: OK, in that case you can use either `=A7=TODAY()+7-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)` or `=(A7>=TODAY())*(A7<TODAY()+7)`